# Highlight line(s)/characters in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, lines, highlighting

**Scenario**

I am currently developing an application. Within this application, I have a TextBox/RichTextBox. I have not decided on the control yet. Within this control, there will be a few paragraphs of text.

**Problem**
I want to be able to highlight a range of lines, or particular characters within that line, using two given numbers. What would the easiest way to do this be?

Comment: you can't use TextBox, TextBox has only one style applied for all text. And clarify _how_ the particular characters are selected by two given numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the TextBox issue, I did not know that previously. Using the sentence:

The quick brown cat jumped over the lazy dog

I would want to feed the numbers 4 and 9, which would highlight from the fourth character to the tenth, so the word "quick".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RichTextBox`. You can't use TextBox, that is because TextBox has only one style applied to all text.

Use the [TextRange.ApplyPropertyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. A `TextRange` is specified by its starting and ending position, which are two `TextPointer`.

Something like this

```
var startingPos = RichTextBox1.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(n1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
var endingPos = startingPos.GetPositionAtOffset(n2 - n1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
var textrange = new TextRange(startingPos, endingPos);

textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.DarkRed);
```

You have to carefully calculate the offsets of the starting and ending positions, taking linebreaks into account.